# Will New Glenn and Falcon 9 compete or serve different markets?

Tags: blue-origin, new-glenn

New Glenn will soon be launching, and I'm wondering: will it compete neck to neck with Falcon 9, and threaten to bite into its market share? Or will it serve an entirely different market? The rocket size is in a whole other league, with New Glenn being roughly twice the diameter of a Falcon 9, and the heavier fuel load should mean heavier payload or higher orbit capacity? Does SpaceX have to worry about New Glenn?

Comment: New Glenn is still some way off being operational (like Starship). When it does come on line the likely competition will be from Starship rather than Falcon 9. Perhaps the question should be does Blue Origin have to worry about Starship?

Comment: "New Glenn will soon be launching" citation needed...